# The cli for aws is blocking with update-function-code

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I have a script to update lambda code from the CLI. It involves several steps:

```
## prepare code
aws lambda update-function-code --function-name my-function --zip-file fileb://my-file --region eu-west-1
## execute code: aws lambda invoke..
```

My problem is that after executing update-function-code, the cli waits for an enter key press, while I don't really care about the result and I would like to go on to the execution.

I've tried different things that haven't worked:
Non interactive mode:

```
bash -c `aws lambda...`
```

Piping enter to the function:

```
printf '\n' | aws lambda...
```

Any idea?

My aws cli version is 2.0.12

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is being caused by AWS CLI v2 using a 'pager', which is a different behaviour from v1.

From [Controlling command output from the AWS CLI - How to set the output’s default pager program](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-output.html#cli-usage-output-pager)
:

> The following example sets the default to disable the use of a pager in the `config` file:
>
> ```
> [default]
> cli_pager=
> ```

Comment: still working, great !

Comment: The `--no-cli-pager` option also works without the need for adding a config file